# Add Entry to Listbox if Entry is a certain length

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to python/tkinter in my lab we use a barcode scanner to scan Sample numbers into a database. I just want to be able to create an entry widget that is able to detect the length of the text that it is given and if it is that length to add it to a listbox. Heres my code:

```
from tkinter import *


def my_tracer(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    SampleNumber = len(e1_var.get())
    t_var.set(SampleNumber)
    if t_var == 8:
        Listbox.insert(END, t_var)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")

SampleList = Listbox(root, selectmode=EXTENDED)
SampleList.pack()

t_var = StringVar()

e1_var = StringVar()
e1_var.trace("w", my_tracer)

e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=e1_var)
e1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I get no error but nothing happens

I am sure there is something fundamental here that i am missing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you just need an entry box and a button and if the text in the entry box is upto a length then, you want to add it to a list, right?

Comment: Ah I'm trying to get it to automatically add the text in the Entrybox to the Listbox if the text in the Entrybox is a certain length. Trying to avoid a button. And thanks!

Comment: take a look at `update` method [here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm)

Comment: you should have said `SampleList.insert(...)` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is wrong:

```
if t_var == 8:
    Listbox.insert(END, t_var)
```

It should be:

```
if SampleNumber == 8:
    SampleList.insert(END, e_var.get())
```

Below is an updated code based on yours:

```
from tkinter import *

def my_tracer(*args):
    txt = e1_var.get().strip()
    if len(txt) == 8:
        SampleList.insert(END, txt)
        e1_var.set('') # clear the entry for next scan

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")

SampleList = Listbox(root, selectmode=EXTENDED)
SampleList.pack()

e1_var = StringVar()
e1_var.trace("w", my_tracer)

e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=e1_var)
e1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

PS: `t_var` is not necessary, so I removed it.

Comment: Thanks Bro that's it! may i ask though why do you use .strip() after the .get()

Comment: `strip()` method removes any leading or trailing empty spaces in the entry text u entered

Comment: @CoolCloud Thanks for your prompt explanation.